# Compiling an XmlSchemaSet with imported schemas

Tags: c#, xsd, .net-core

I'm trying to create an `XmlSchemaSet` against the SAML 2.0 set of schema definitions, starting with the protocol schema here: https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd

```
var set = new XmlSchemaSet();

XmlSchema schema;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(
    "https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd"))
{
    schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Message));
}

set.Add(schema);

set.Compile();
```

When `Compile` is called, the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaException
Type 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:EncryptedElementType' is not declared.
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.InternalValidationCallback(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.BaseProcessor.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
   at System.Xml.Schema.BaseProcessor.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaException e)
   at System.Xml.Schema.Compiler.CompileElement(XmlSchemaElement xe)
   at System.Xml.Schema.Compiler.Compile()
   at System.Xml.Schema.Compiler.Execute(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, SchemaInfo schemaCompiledInfo)
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet.Compile()
   at XSD.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

The type specified `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion:EncryptedElementType` appears in the namespace imported at the top of the schema:

```
<import
    namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    schemaLocation="saml-schema-assertion-2.0.xsd"/>
```

Using Fiddler, I can't see the application making any attempts at retrieving the imported schema.

Why don't these import statements appear to be working with the `XmlSchemaSet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default behaviour of the `XmlSchemaSet` is to not try to resolve any external schemas. To this this, the `XmlResolver` property must be set. The go-to resolver implementation is `XmlUrlResolver`:

```
set.XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
```

The important thing is to set this property **before** adding any schemas to the set. The call to `Add` performs "pre-processing" on the schema, which includes resolving any import statements. Assigning the `XmlResolver` after calling `Add` appears to have no effect.

The application code needs to be:

```
var set = new XmlSchemaSet
{
    // Enable resolving of external schemas.
    XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver()
};

XmlSchema schema;
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(
    "https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd"))
{
    schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Message));
}

set.Add(schema);

set.Compile();
```

**NOTE** The above code still does not actually produce the desired result due to problems loading the schemas from w3.org, however the imported SAML schema is resolved successfully.